# How to Send the Contents of a Text File to the Clipboard from the Command Line in OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, clipboard

I would like to send the contents of a text file to the OS X clipboard.

Does Mac OS X have a built in way to do this, or will I have write a script to do this myself?

Or in other words, how do I access the clipboard from the command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nevermind, figured it out.

```
 pbcopy < filename

  #copies contents of a text, rtf, or eps file to the clipboard


  pbpaste

  #pastes content of clipboard to stdout
```

Comment: That's awesome. Where did you find this info, and are there other cool conduits between CLI world and GUI world?

Comment: @slim Just, for example, google the title of the question

Answer (score 2):

Yep, that's the way to go. Of course, you can also pipe output into it, ie, `echo "test" | pbcopy`.